# Can not use specific float32 values as map key

Tags: go, floating-point

Using float32 as map key returns unexpected result

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    result := make(map[float32]map[float32]float32)

    var t1 float32 = 1586238540
    var t2 float32 = 1586238600

    result[t1] = map[float32]float32{1:1,2:2}
    result[t2] = map[float32]float32{3:3,4:4}

    fmt.Println(result[t1])
    fmt.Println(result[t2])
}
```

```
map[3:3 4:4]
map[3:3 4:4]
```

Go version: `go version go1.14 linux/amd64`

Changing `result` to `map[float64]map[float32]float32` and `t1`, `t2` accordingly gives the right result.

What could be a reason for this weird behavior?

Comment: David Goldberg "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" 1991 should be know not only by computer scientists but by every programmer too. Read it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A 32 bit float has a 23 bit mantissa, with an implicit preceeding highest 1 bit. So the maximum value representable by the mantissa is 2²⁴-1 = 16777215. In other words only integer numbers between -16777215 to 16777215 can be **exactly** represented as a 32 bit float.

Your two values 1586238540 and 1586238600 are outside that range and both get truncated to the same value 1586238592. And it's that truncated value that's being used as key for the map.

Comment: oh, of course, did not realize timestamps are out of range. Thank you

Comment: They're not out of range. They're out-of-precision so to speak. Using floats for timestamps is a terrible idea anyway. You should use plain integers (preferrably 64 bit ints) and if you need fractional second precision, count milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

https://play.golang.org/p/Fx78BbmnXIE, 1586238540 and 1586238600 are same in memory

Answer (score 1):

if you add this to your code

```
fmt.Println(t1)
fmt.Println(t2)
```

you'll see `1.5862386e+09` as result for both because the value is too big for a float32. with float64 you'll see the proper value printed

```
1.58623854e+09
1.5862386e+09
```

for more info [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)